# AD log message showing E-mail of user object creation

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, users, windows-event-log

I am referencing the active directory log message (4720) which shows 'User Principal Name' as an email address.

However there is another email address found when viewing the actual User Object 'general' tab, which is not used for logging in.

What log message would have the creation of the email address shown under general user information, instead of the login email address related to the domain of the account?

---

Event ID 5136 shows the updates. LDAP mail updates.

Answer (score 0):

check for event ID 4738.

refer this article http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17055.event-ids-when-a-new-user-account-is-created-on-active-directory.aspx